# Center map and show balloon when clicking address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using the newest version of Gmaps4Rails with a Ruby on Rails application.  I am able to display the map with markers properly, but I don't know how to interact with the map.

I have a list of addresses on the right side of the page and a google map to the left.  THe google map displays all of the addresses listed on the right side of the page.  Once we get more than 20 addresses, it becomes hard to identify where the marker is on the map when looking through the list on the right side of the page!

Is it possible to make the map center and popup the balloon for the marker when a user clicks the related address on the right side of the page?

**_map.js.erb**

```
<!-- Google Maps JS -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript" />
<script src='http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript' />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

**index.html.haml**

```
.map-wrapper
  #map
  .large-3.columns.search_box
    %h4 Addresses

    .large-12.columns
      = link_to 'Add Location', new_location_path, class: 'new_record_button'
      = form_for locations_path, method: 'get' do |f|
        = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
        = f.submit 'search', class: 'search_button', name: nil

    .large-12.columns.location
      - @locations.each do |location|
        .location_record
          = link_to location.name, '#', :onclick => 'aaabbb(marker[1]);'
          .address_info
            = location.address
            %br/
            #{location.city}, #{location.state}. #{location.zip}

= raw render 'map.js'
```

**controller**

```
def index
  @locations = Location.search(params[:search]).order('created_at desc')

  set_gmap_markers
end
```

Comment: you have this exact example in the doc: http://apneadiving.github.io/

Comment: I just saw the example - thank you! So I can be clear on what this does, is it the bindLiToMarker js method that makes the onclick magic happen?

Comment: yes it is, namely it binds li to the marker :)

Comment: I tried to integrate the example, but i'm a JS lightweight and can't figure it out. Since I am looping through the @hash values in the view, I can't bind the JS on_click as the example page shows. In my onclick method, I added marker[1] to make sure it would load, but I get an error. Can you help?! Thank you!!

Comment: in the example, the sidebar is created by the javascript

Comment: Is there an example of allowing a rails generated list to have this functionality? I just don't know how to pass the javascript value of the selected hash to the JS method that centers/focuses the map.